# Вывод результата регулярного выражения

Tags: php

```
$str=file_get_contents("http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=41");
preg_match_all('/(Глава: .*?")/', $str, $name); 
$name = implode("", $name[0]);
```

Как теперь вывести пропарсенное. Что надо писать после оператора echo или print, чтобы вывелся текст.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте **var_dump($name);** и думаю увидите где и что лежит.

Comment: Знаком с пшп не так давно и увы не знаю, что делает эта функция. Подскажите что-то более конкретное.

Comment: var_dump($name) покажет вам в каких ячейках массива что лежит. Ну и соответственно как и написано в коде, то что вам нужно скорее всего будет в $name[0]. Так что можно вывести содержимое именно этой ячейки массива echo $name[0];

Answer (score 1):

```
...
 $name = implode("", $name[0]);
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично с функцией print:

```
...
 $name = implode("", $name[0]);
 print $foo;
```

почитать и посмотреть примеры функций можно тут:
функция [print](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)
функция [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)